# Having trouble assigning char pointers to structs in loop

Tags: c, pointers, struct, while-loop

I'm trying to loop through the contents of a stream to dynamically generate nodes in a list, given the contents of each line that I read. I have a struct that I defined below:

```
struct info {
     char *mystring;
     char *file;
     int line_no;
     struct info *next;
};
```

I use this loop to iterate through the stream:

```
while(1) {      
      char t [KMAX];
      char* file;
      char* line_no;
      char* text;
      if (fgets(t, KMAX, file_pipe) != NULL) {
           file = strtok (t, delimiter);
           line_no = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
           int line = atoi(line_no);
           text = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
           add(&head, text, line, file);
      }
```

I know the variables are passed correctly to my add function, because I print them out each time and I can verify it. However, the problem comes when I try to print the list. It just prints the last line of text and file name, but the integer value changes accordingly. My guess is that it has something to do with the array being destoryed and being re-created each time in the same block of memory, so the pointers get changed each time.

I'm not sure what the proper method is to go about fixing this problem. Do I modify my while loop somehow and use char pointers in a difference manner, or should I change my struct somehow to hold the variables, instead of just using pointers? I would appreciate any feedback!

**EDIT : Added more code**

```
 void add(struct info **x, char * text, int line_no, char * file) {
 struct info* current = *x;
 struct info* newInfo;


 newInfo = malloc(sizeof(struct info));
 (*newInfo).next = NULL;
 (*newInfo).grepstring = text;
 (*newInfo).line_no = line_no;
 (*newInfo).file = file;

 if (current == NULL) { //indicates the head is null, special case
      *x = newInfo;
 } else {
      //get to the end of the list
      while ((*current).next != NULL) {
           current = (*current).next;
      }
      //apends node to the end of the list
      (*current).next = newInfo;
 }
```

}

Comment: The fault must be in either the add or print list code.  Could you please post them.

Comment: To be able to determine the cause of your problem we would need to see where exactly you issue the print call that you mention. 

Also to be pedantic I would suggest checking for strtok returning null after each call which would mean that string t null terminating character has been found

Comment: Well, what is it? 'struct info' or 'struct saying'?

Comment: Posted additional code, and I mean struct info. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `char* text`, what you are doing is allocating a `char*` on the *stack*. `strtok` isn't pointing it to some newly allocated memory, it's pointing it into the stack-allocated space of `t`.

This memory is lost when it *falls out of scope*, which happens at the bottom of each iteration of the `while` loop. Any references to its address might point to the correct contents, or nothing, or some other random value after that point - the behavior they exhibit is undefined.

You need the contents of each `struct info` to survive the loop (and, presumably, continue to survive for the foreseeable future). To do this you must make a *heap allocation*. In C this is done via the `malloc` function.

In your `add` method, say:

```
char* text_copy = malloc(strlen(text)+1); // +1 for trailing NUL character
strcpy(text_copy, text);
```

This will create new memory on the heap, having the same contents as the original text.

You should do this for all the contents of the `struct info`, since at the moment they're all pointers into the stack-allocated `t` buffer.

You must `free` the memory again when you are done with it, but it will last until then.

Comment: I think you're right... modifying my code to include a memory allocation of the text worked. When/where should I deallocate- at the end when I destroy the list?

Comment: @thomascirca Whenever you no longer need the contents. Whenever you call `malloc`, somewhere there must be a corresponding `free`, or you have a *memory leak*. In this particular case, you probably want to loop through and `free` everything when you "destroy the list", as you say.

Comment: I'd just like to add that you don't need to worry about freeing if your program is going to terminate soon, because all the memory will be freed by the OS at that point.

Comment: @DavidGrayson While that is true, I generally consider relying on it a bad practice. I've found in the past that it's too easy to add some more code "just before the application exits", and next thing you know you have 300MB of leftovers clinging to your VMEM numbers while you do "just one more task"... Better to just not forget in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us what `add()` does, but apparently it just assigns the results of calling `strtok()` directly to the members of a struct. You can't do that -- use `strdup()` (or `malloc()` and `strcpy()`) to make a copy of each `char *` before assigning them to a struct member. The pointers `strtok()` returns point into that `char` buffer, and they become invalid with each new loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The only buffer you ever created for holding strings was `t`, which you made at the top of your while loop:

```
char t [KMAX];
```

So all of your `char *` pointers will be pointing somewhere into that buffer, but that's a problem because you change the contents buffer every time you call `fgets`.  After you are done reading the input, the only text you actually have stored in RAM will be the data from the last call to `fgets`.

You could change the `add` function so it allocates new buffers and copies the strings to them.  There is already a function that does that for you and it is called [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup).  Something like this would work (though I have not tested it):

```
void add(struct info **x, char * text, int line_no, char * file) {
 ...
 newInfo = malloc(sizeof(struct info));
 newInfo->next = NULL;
 newInfo->grepstring = strdup(text);
 newInfo->line_no = line_no;
 newInfo->file = strdup(file);
 ...
}
```